# API for collection of polymorphic objects

Tags: c++, c++11

Assume I have a collection of polymorphic objects. My naive example implementation would be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Parent{
    virtual void print() const {std::cout<<name <<"\n";}
    std::string name{"parent"};
};

struct ChildA:Parent{
    virtual void print() const {std::cout<<name <<descr<<"\n";}

    std::string name{"child A"};
    std::string descr{" is awesome"};
};

struct ChildB:Parent{
    virtual void print() const {std::cout<<name <<"\n";}
    std::string name{"child B"};
};

class Collection {
public:
   void print(){
       for (const auto& entry:data){
       entry->print();
       }
   }

  void add_data(std::unique_ptr<Parent> p){
    data.emplace_back(std::move(p));
  }

private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> data;
};

int main(){
Collection coll;
coll.add_data(std::make_unique<ChildA>(ChildA()));
coll.add_data(std::make_unique<ChildB>(ChildB()));
coll.print();
}
```

Is there a more elegant way? Can I somehow just pass by (const) reference? I really dislike the make_unique in the API.

As a solution I came up with the following:

```
template <typename T>
void add_data(const T& d){
    data.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>(d));
}
```

which can be used more naturally:

```
coll.add_data(ChildA())
```

A related problem is the constructor of a wrapper class. Maybe:

```
class Wrapper{
public:

template <typename T>
Wrapper(const T& p):entry{std::make_unique<T>(p)}{}
template <typename T>
Wrapper(const T&& p):entry{std::make_unique<T>(p)}{}

void print(){
    entry->print();
    }

private:
std::unique_ptr<Parent> entry;
};
```

[live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59168b2d42ff732a)

The problem seems very common so I would like to ask: What is the "best practice" solution?

Comment: `template <typename T>
void add_data(const T& d){
    data.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>(d));
}` is the way to go.  You can add a static assert or use SFINAE to constrain the template as well if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I guess my solution in combination with concepts will be the way to go in the future.